# jasper not formatting excel data types

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a Jasper Report which seems to be exporting fine in all formats except Excel.

The below sample is of a column that should be formatted as currency but shows incorrectly.

[image]

Here are the jasper properties i'm using...

```
out = new FileOutputStream(file);
JExcelApiExporter exporterXLS = new JExcelApiExporter();

exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.CREATE_CUSTOM_PALETTE, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.FALSE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS, Boolean.FALSE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);

exporterXLS.exportReport();
```

I've tried both Jasper 4.0 and 4.5.  I think it has to do with a dependency but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed!

Instead of using the `JRXlsExporterParameter` class i used the parameters as follows and it worked!

```
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.create.custom.palette", "false");
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet", "false");
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows", "false");
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns", "false");
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background", "true");
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type", "false");
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.size.fix.enabled", "false");
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics", "false");
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span", "false");
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.border", "false");
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.background", "false");
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.max.rows.per.sheet", "0");
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text", "true");
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.use.timezone", "false");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add ***`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern`*** property for your `textField` element in jrxml file.

You can find the sample [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/index.html#xlsfeatures).