# jasper not formatting excel data types for number properly

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I was facing an issue with formats of fields having numeric values. I tried code mentioned in posts [jasper not formatting excel data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990957/jasper-not-formatting-excel-data-types)
and [JasperReports 5.6: JRXlsExporter.setParameter is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117878/jasperreports-5-6-jrxlsexporter-setparameter-is-deprecated).

But now i am facing another issue: these fields are having custom format ;;.

However when they are selected they do have right values.
I have tried both `SimpleXlsReportConfiguration` with `xlsReportConfiguration.setDetectCellType(true);` and `exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);`

here is the text field expression.


                    
                    
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    
                    
                        
                    
                    
                 
But both are resulting in same. Any pointers what I am missing.
JasperReports version is 5.5.2

Comment: Show your jrxml definition for one textField that you export to excel

Comment: <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Long"><![CDATA[$F{incoming_number}]]></textFieldExpression>

Comment: I can't see the pattern? and please [edit] your question instead of passing comment when including more info to question.

Comment: Thanks after using pattern for Long and Integer also issue is resolved now.